# Circular logarithmic scale made with AI, how?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, scale

**Hello everybody!**

I have to do a circular slide rule. 
Is there any nice way to make the *logarithmic (circular) scale* with Illustrator?

**All ideas are welcome! Thanks in advance!**

Here's a picture that shows what I am looking for:

[image: Logarithmic scale]

Comment: Hi and welcome, you should probably write a script?

Comment: have you tried anything? it's always nice to show some effort, the question gets better chances of receiving an answer

Comment: Hi nuffield, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the *Rectangular Grid Tool*, with one row and however many columns you need. Then you can use the *Skew* option if you need the non-linear dividers:

[image]

Combine a number of grids to create your ruler:

[image]

Create an *Art Brush* from your ruler by dragging it the the *Brushes* panel and apply your brush to a circle:

[image]

Comment: Thank you super-much! I will try that! Thank you! I have to add that this FORUM is not the easiest one to use - for me, hah haa!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. You can "accept" an answer if you feel it sufficiently answers your question by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer. This helps everyone out with a bit of "rep" and prevents the question popping up in our list of unanswered questions.

Comment: If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!